# Detect changed data in SQL database without "touching" the database itself

Tags: sql, database

We are developing a product that does auditing on external databases.

What we aim to achieve is that we could install this over an existing database then detect and log the changes *without* touching the mentioned database at all.

I know that this can be done with triggers very easily. However, we were thinking if it is possible to run our SW without violating the customer's DB. The solution -if there's one- would be preferably database agnostic.

I'd drop the option of polling as it can miss a lot of changes and/or can be very resource heavy.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that each DBMS would be different. For example, SQL Server has [SQL Server Audit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280386.aspx). And common sense tells me that any kind of auditing/tracing would increase load on the server, so it will definitely affect existing database.

Comment: Well, first, there's no DBMS product-agnostic solution to this.

Comment: There are solutions to this. I guess reading the transaction-log is the most common. But this question is super-broad I think. You are planning to build a software product, but do not have even the high-level idea on *how* to do it?

Comment: We have a lot of ideas, we are just looking for the least invasive one. The less fuss, the happier the customers are.

Comment: So which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? But the two requirements "*install this over an existing database*" and "*without touching the mentioned database at all*" contradict each other - at least in my opinion. You can't install anything into a database without touching the database

Comment: Right now the client is using Firebird but mysql, postgres, ms sql would be a target as well.